# ASP.NET Membership and dynamic Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Section A:- What i need is simple a website where i can create several companies.

Section B:- Now each company can create/update/delete and manage it's own users. Each company additionally can create pages for each user role e.g company A can setup a page for it's Admin users as landing page after log in and some other page for users with different roles.
As for as users concerned i have implemented this section using ASP.NET membership.

**Question:-**  
**Q1 :-** How can i create companies through programming?? So later on user's and there actions can be performed based on membership of each company??

Comment: I would use a master file and check there.

Comment: Are you intending each company to have their own unique site with its own unique url?  Or will they come to your site only at your url and login with their company login?

Comment: No i don't need a unique url (ur rewriting or what so ever) i just need a single site where users of each company come and login with their company login and after that based on there company setup they can use the site